# Erro ao instalar magento

Tags: ubuntu, magento

Estou tentando instalar o magento em meu localhost, porém quando cheguei na etapa de colocar o banco de dados, usuario e senha eu tive que marcar a opção de skip base URL (estou usando virtual host).

a pagina aparentemente travou, demorou mais de 3 minutos (ou até mais) para carregar, e quando dei um refresh na pagina só aparecia um erro:

> There has been an error processing your request
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
> Error log record number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

procurei no google como resolver e achei o metodo de renomear o arquivo `local.xml.sample` na pasta errors por `local.xml` e de alterar o trecho de código em `lib/zend/cache/backend/file.php` que antes era:

```
protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => null,
```

por:

```
protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

e depois criar uma pasta tmp na raiz do magento, porém não aparecia mais nada, nem erro e nem o painel para instalação então habilitei a linha que exibi os erros na pagina principal e agora o erro que está aparecendo é:

> Warning: include(/var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247

Comment: Rafael, provavelmente o banco de dados não foi instalado completamente já que você abortou esse processo. Confere se o banco está completo, se não estiver, refaça a instalação, não se esqueça de limpar o banco e excluir o arquivo local.xml antes.

Comment: Verifique suas permissões: `failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

Não recomendo que altere nenhum arquivo do core do Magento como fez acima.
Os erros deste tipo são ocultados por segurança e salvos em var/report no seu Magento. Se o Magento não tiver permissão pra escrever nesta pasta, ele irá salvar em /tmp/magento (na raíz do servidor).

Se o seu banco realmente estiver com as credenciais certas no app/etc/local.xml você deve ser capaz de testar no terminal digitando `mysql -h<host> -u<usuario> -p -D<base>`.

Se estiver tudo certo, verifique também:

- Existencia do arquivo app/etc/local.xml
- Formato do campo  dentro do app/etc/local.xml
- Permissoes de arquivos no magento (mais [aqui](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html))
- Existencia da pasta var dentro do Magento

Espero ter ajudado.